# is unordered_set thread safe if data race is irrelevant?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety

I would like to have threads add unique floats to a list, and first thought about approaching it by inserting into an `unordered_map<float,int>` where the values does not matter (which essentially is an `unordered_set<float>`). The threads could override each other with values 1 in the same key, ie. it doesn't matter if Thread 1 wrote value 1 first, or Thread 2, because in the end, it will just end up as 1. As such, data races should be irrelevant.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <thread>
#include <set>

std::unordered_set<float> mySet;

void someTask(int i) {
    mySet.insert(i % 3);
}

int main()
{
    std::thread threads[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {  
     threads[i] = std::thread(someTask, i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {  
     threads[i].join();
    }    

    for (auto const& mySetVal : mySet) {
     std::cout << mySetVal << std::endl;    // Oddly, mySet might have duplicates
    }    

    std::set<float> mySet_( mySet.begin(), mySet.end() ); // Make a new ordered set, and removing duplicates along the way

    for (auto const& mySetVal : mySet_) {
     std::cout << mySetVal << std::endl;   // Would this always produce the expected result of 0,1,2?
    }
}
```

However mySet despite being an `unordered_set` has duplicates, and I'm guessing this is due to a race condition while reading for the key, and ended up inserting twice? But when I replace mySet with a `unordered_map<float,int>`, there are still duplicates- I would've thought even if there is a race condition, and although we can't guarantee which thread will execute first, in the end, the threads can override one another without any harm.

So why are there duplicates?

And by removing the duplicates at the end, is this thread-safe, or would it produce the expected results of 0,1,2 consistently/reliably? If not, a thread-safe solution for the code above would be awesome!

Comment: You need to prevent concurrent access (at the very least modification - but even reads can be problematic in a map if an access is made to a key that doesn't exist yet). I don't know why you think this race is somehow safe, even when faced with evidence that it is not.

Comment: Have you considered re-hashing when inserting new elements???

Comment: But your result is not **expected** if your set, which entire purpose is not to have duplicates, has duplicates.

Comment: So from what I understand, the race is indeed not safe and making duplicate entries, and that violates the properties of a set, which is probably very bad practice I'm guessing. But more for personal interest, if we know and expect the behavior from the race (ie. it will cause a set with duplicates), then wouldn't we be able to still say the results are as expected?

Comment: You managed to break `set` guarantees, which is broken already. Threading is also about timing so some errors may occur only rarely. Thread-safe is a guarantee though, and even at a 99.9% success rate is not thread-safe. Also, consider portablility, i.e. that code behaves correctly with different compilers on different platforms. I can imagine that your compiler and platform in combination could give you the guarantee that the code behaves as you expect it to, but that guarantee may break when ported to a different compiler or platform. It may even break for the next version of these.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thank you so much, that gives me a much better understanding on why this is considered not thread-safe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All standard containers are safe to read from concurrently and you can concurrently modify different elements of the same container, but not the same element: 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Thread_safety

You need to synchronize writes to the container if there is possibility of overlap to avoid undefined behavior (e.g. using `std::mutex`). (the answer to your second question is yes, but `mySet` might be corrupted due to concurrent write so you cannot assume it will have the inserted values)